# How to skip double quotes without using single quotes in the below scenario in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

```
<body onload="myFunction("<%=request.getServletPath%>")">
```

and

```
<body onload="myFunction("${application.map["variableName"]}")">
```

I know the workaround with single quotes, But It doesn't fit my use case scenario.

Answer (score 3):

By NOT using inline event handlers which are NOT recommended

```js
function myFunction(parm) {
  console.log(parm);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  myFunction('${application.map["variableName"]}');
})

//or 

const mapName = '${application.map["variableName "]}';
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  myFunction(mapName);
})
```

Escaping does not work

```html
<body onload="console.log(\"somevar\")">
```

Entities do

```html
<body onload="console.log(&quot;somevar&quot;)">
```

Also using a hidden div works (if you have newlines in the rendered string)

```js
function show(str) {
  console.log(str);
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  show(document.getElementById("appMap").innerText.trim());
})
```

```css
#applicationMap {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="appMap">
  ${application.map["variableName"]}
<div>
```

Comment: What about for this? <body onload="myFunction("<%=request.getServletPath%>")">

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but escaping quotes with \ is not working. The page is rendered as it is \"result"\

Comment: Then do not use inline onload as I suggested

Comment: I added yet another vetrsion

Answer (score 2):

Use the escape character '\':

```
<body onload="myFunction(\"${application.map[\"variableName\"]}\")">
```